# URL issue with Codeigniter (Azure AD reply URI)

Tags: javascript, php, azure, codeigniter

I searched for hours but didn't find any solution. I want users to connect with Office 365 and use an Azure App to do this with a javascript single page app. I work in local and all works fine when I test the code in a basic www/testapp folder. But when I use the code in my Codeigniter project, also in a basic assets folder, I get this error message :

> AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the
>   reply urls configured for the application: 'xxxxxxx'.

The redirection URI in Azure portal is correctly setted but the error is still here. So I think it comes from Codeigniter parameters (URI redirection, etc.) but I don't know how to fix it.

Thx for your help !

> AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the
>   reply urls configured for the application: 'xxxxxxx'.

Comment: So did you look at the urls you have coded into your code. That would be a good starting point.

Comment: share your code snippet please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thanks for your replies ! The problem came from Codeigniter config.php file. The base_url parameter was empty, so the url in localhost was 'http://[:1]/mysite/' instead of 'http://localhost/mysite/'. Just had to set base_url information and now it works.